# Who can give me the code of SFA model(polyp segmentation)?

Tags: pytorch, semantic-segmentation, medical-imaging, unet-neural-network

The code in github of the paper "Selective Feature Aggregation Network with Area-Boundary Constraints for Polyp Segmentation"(MICCAI 2019) had been deleted by the author. I extremely need it for a contrast test. Can someone give me the code if you have saved it previously. Thanks a lot.

There's no source of the code in Internet. Can someone give me the code if you have saved it previously. Thanks a lot.